# How do i convert a Named num [1:4] to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, homework

newbie to r, taking The R [Programming Environment](https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming-environment/home/welcome) from coursera. one of the assignments is to select some columns from a data frame and find the means.

the code below seems to get the correct answer, but the answer should be a data frame.

```
wc_2 <- worldcup %>% 
  select(Time, Passes, Tackles, Saves) %>%
    colMeans()
```

How do i convert this to a data frame? i tried: `wc_2<-as.data.frame(wc_2)` but that gets it column wise. i do not see any way to pass the rows and columns or do a transpose in what i assume is a data frame constructor.

perhaps this can be done as part of the pipe?

thanks

edit: i got it to work:

```
means <- worldcup %>% 
  select(Time, Passes, Tackles, Saves) %>%
    colMeans()
wc_2<-data.frame(t(matrix(means)))
colnames(wc_2)<-names(means)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way to transpose a `data.frame` (or `data.table`) is to use the `transpose` function found in [the data.table package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki).

It means you might have to install it: `install.packages("data.table")`.
This give you a function that will do what you want. Here is a demo how to use it:

```
library(data.table)    # makes the transpose function available

col_names <- colnames(worldcup)      # keep track of original column names
wc_2 <- colMeans(worldcup)           # compute the means
wc_2 <- transpose(as.data.frame(wc_2))              # this gives you generic column names
colnames(wc_2) <- col_names          # reapply the column names
```

Or combining it with your example (not fully tested):

```
library(magrittr)    # to import the pipe operator: %>%

wc_2 <- worldcup %>% 
  select(Time, Passes, Tackles, Saves) %>%
    colMeans() %>% as.data.frame() %>% transpose()       # you might need to put a dot (`.`) in the empty brackets to pass the argument before the pipe operator
```

then maybe add the names you would like:

```
colnames(wc_2) <- col_names
```

If you like the sound of the package, I recommend going through the mini intro, built in to the package:

```
install.packages("data.table")        # install it
library(data.table)                   # load it
example(data.table)                   # run the examples section of ?
```

Comment: it does not like transpose. also, the result needs to be a data frame.

Comment: Oops, I missed one function - you still need the `as.data.frame()` function on the output of `colMeans()`. I edited the third line of my example to show it: ` wc_2 <- transpose(as.data.frame(wc_2))`. Also added it to the chain of the piped version.

Comment: t seems to work instead of transpose.

Comment: @RayTayek -  I don't think you even need the matrix function. This returns the expected dataframe for me: `data.frame(t(colMeans(worldcup['col1'])))`

Comment: yes, it seems to give the same result with out the call to matrix()